# select distinct is taking lot of time on mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 10 million rows and the below query is taking a lot of time even with the index. I removed distinct it was quite faster. Any reason why DISTINCT is taking more time. Also, can I rewrite this without distinct?

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(b2.id) AS max_id 
    FROM  node_ancestors b2, node_data b3 
    WHERE b2.ancestor_node_id = b3.node_id 
    GROUP BY b2.node_id, b2.ancestor_node_id

nodes_ids(ancestor_node_id,node_id)-->Index
```

Comment: you don't need DISTINCT with GROUP BY

Comment: Use INNER JOIN instead of comma. This is old concept.

Comment: @RahulBiswas Can you please elaborate on which comma and how to perform inner join?

Comment: Try to create and index `node_ancestors  (ancestor_node_id, node_id, id)`.

Comment: @PSK This is not correct. The output list contains aggregated value which can be the same for different groups.

Comment: @Akina Thanks but  this is production data and  data size is huge and adding index now is  the last option.

Comment: What is the logic of this query? What is the reason to obtain aggregated value for some groups without the info about the groups itself?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you about this?

Comment: That index seems impossible since it has columns from different tables.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Or maybe b2 and b3 both have a `node_id`, yet you are not `JOINing` on that column??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(b2.id) AS max_id   
FROM  node_ancestors b2
INNER JOIN node_data b3 
        ON b2.ancestor_node_id = b3.node_id 
GROUP BY b2.node_id, b2.ancestor_node_id
```

For optimization purpose. Multiple value comes as per group condition. So subquery is used here for retrieving max id among result set.

```
    SELECT MAX(t.max_id) max_id
    FROM (SELECT MAX(b2.id) AS max_id   
FROM  node_ancestors b2
INNER JOIN node_data b3 
        ON b2.ancestor_node_id = b3.node_id 
GROUP BY b2.node_id, b2.ancestor_node_id) t
```

If need multiple value then

```
SELECT t.max_id
    FROM (SELECT MAX(b2.id) AS max_id   
FROM  node_ancestors b2
INNER JOIN node_data b3 
        ON b2.ancestor_node_id = b3.node_id 
GROUP BY b2.node_id, b2.ancestor_node_id) t
```

Comment: Hi @gauravagastya please you can use inner join instead of comma with above example.

Comment: Thanks  .This works but it runs very slow. Do I need  DISTINCT and GROUP BY both?

Comment: Hi @gauravagastya do you need only single value or GROUP BY b2.node_id, b2.ancestor_node_id wise value. please explain.

Comment: @gauravagastya *Do I need DISTINCT and GROUP BY both?* Distinct is excess only if this column `b2.id` is defined as unique (maybe primary key) in the table.

Comment: @gauravagastya if you provide logic then I can help you to optimization.

Comment: @Akina yes b2.id is primary key

Comment: Hi @gauravagastya please check the new one. let me know if this one help you.

Comment: @gauravagastya If so then remove DISTINCT - PK values cannot have duplicates.

Comment: Hi @Akina if b2.node_id and b3.node_id is different and b2.node_id is used in GROUP BY clause. So multiple value can be come. That's why use subquery for final max value.

Comment: @RahulBiswas  I had to modify your query SELECT  max_id
    FROM (SELECT MAX(b2.id) AS max_id   
FROM  node_ancestors b2
INNER JOIN node_data b3 
        ON b2.ancestor_node_id = b3.node_id 
GROUP BY b2.node_id, b2.ancestor_node_id) temp . This works

Comment: @gauravagastya is b2.node_id and b3.node_id same? b2.node_id is used in GROUP BY clause. So multiple value can be come according to group by columns combination. So another max can have required here. Please check this. I've use another max for avoiding multiple value. if required multiple value then remove max.

Comment: @RahulBiswas The query you gave doesn't give multiple rows.It just returns one row which is max of max_id

Comment: @gauravagastya please check my last query.  Hope it'll meet your expectation. If my answer is helpful to you then mark it as useful and accepted. Please don't take it otherwise.

Comment: @RahulBiswas *if b2.node_id and b3.node_id is different and b2.node_id is used in GROUP BY clause. So  multiple value can be come. That's why use subquery for final max value.* One b2.id may match only one b2.node_id and hence only one b3.node_id. So you cannot receive the same b2.id for different b3.node_id.